# Java - Read the file within the package from another package

Tags: java, inputstream

I have a Java project with the package **com.myproject.schema** where I have the test.txt file.
To read the content of that file from the package **com.myproject.imp.tasks** (from which I want to read the file)
I'm trying the example below using the ClassLoader approach.

```
InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/com/myproject/schema/test.txt");
```

However, getting `null` as a result.

Could you please advise some alternative way or how to fix this?

Comment: Have you verified that the text file has actually been copied into your classpath?

Comment: Hello @ThomasBehr, yes it is and also the file physically is there, that's why as the last option I've asked here for help. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Are you running in a module?  Is the other class in a different module?  From the [Class.getResourceAsStream documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String)):  “Resources in named modules are subject to the rules for encapsulation specified in the Module `getResourceAsStream` method and so this method returns null when the resource is a non-".class" resource in a package that is not open to the caller's module.”

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks to all for your replies.
 I could solve the issue. The `getResourceAsStream()` was looking for the text file inside the directory where the java classes are compiled and stored, however, the file was kept only in the non-compiled package, so that's why was not possible to find.Copying the file properly, the issue has gone.